# How to solve Notepad++ crashes after DSpellCheck plugin misconfiguration (Dos)?

Tags: notepad++

When you open notepad++, click on plugins and go to DSpellCheck and then click Settings. In the "hunspell dictionaries path" field, enter about 4000 to 80000 'A'. Then it crashes. When it is opened again it again crashes. I tries to uninstall it and remove the old files in the folder. the it continued crashing again.

How to solve it not to crash again ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please locate the file **DSpellCheck.ini**.
It can be either in directory

```
<directory of notepad++ exe>\plugins\Config\
```

or in directory

```
%AppData%\plugins\Config\
```

First directory you can determine from properties of Notepad++ shortcut. Second directory you can visit by typing `%appdata%` into path line of **My Computer** window and pressing Enter.

Content of DSpellCheck.ini can look like:

```
[SpellCheck]
Autocheck=0
Check_Those_\_Not_Those=0
User_Hunspell_Path=AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
System_Hunspell_Path=BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
```

You have either `User_Hunspell_Path` or `System_Hunspell_Path` set to invalid value, see the above example. Remove the line, save config and restart Notepad++

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `DSpellCheck.ini` file has `Check_Those_\_Not_Those=0`.

### Fix Details:

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and enter following command:

   ```
   notepad "%AppData%\Notepad++\plugins\config\DSpellCheck.ini"
   ```
2. Replace the text with the below text or just add the required line.

   ```
   [SpellCheck]
   Check_Those_\_Not_Those=0
   ```
3. Save the file

After fixing the ini file, NotePad++ should be able to run without DSpellCheck crashing.

### FYI:

I had DSpellCheck installed for over 4 months without any issues, and one day after removing a different **unrelated** plugin, notepad++ started to crash.
I determined the crash was being triggered by DSpellCheck, because NotePad++ didn't crash when I removed the DSpellCheck folder from the plugin directory.

After reading miroxlav's comment, I examine the `DSpellCheck.ini`, and found that it only had one entry (`Library=2`).  So I added `Check_Those_\_Not_Those=0`, and NotePad++ stopped crashing after the change.

### Note:

The Notepad++ path is missing in path listed by miroxlav. Here's the corrected path:

```
%AppData%\Notepad++\plugins\config\DSpellCheck.ini
```

I found the plugin binaries in standard folder `C:\Program Files\Notepad++\plugins` and even though that path has a config folder, the INI files are stored in the users `AppData` path on Windows 10:

```
%AppData%\Notepad++\plugins\config
```

Answer (score 0):

DSpellcheck.dll often crashes with a "bad allocation" exception when files contain binary data. I selected Plugins/Open Plugins Folder, navigated to the DSpellCheck folder and renamed the DLL to "DSpellCheck is f---ing buggy.dll", then restarted Notepad++.