# Set DSpellCheck in Notepad++ back to using Notepad++ context menu

Tags: notepad++, spell-check

I have mistakenly set DSpellCheck to use own button for word correction:

[image]

Now, each time I am trying to change this:

[image]

This is not possible / this is being ignored, because clicking on *OK*, *Cancel* or *Apply* brings no effect (i.e. configuration window is not closed). I can only close this configuration window using red x button and after Notepad++ restart no change can be observed (and again buttons are used for spelling correction).

Which configuration flag controls this or how can I modify this setting using configuration file (like shown in [this answer](https://superuser.com/q/743734/156554)) and not using DSpellCheck's configuration UI (which seems to be buggy)?

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling DSpellCheck?

Comment: @DavidPostill Yes, but I can't. It seems kind of "jammed" or sth. I am using a standard way (N++ > Plugins > Plugin Admin... > Installed > DSpellCheck > Remove), Plugin Admin confirms and restarts N++ and after restart DSpellCheck is still there. Weird.